# Model designer: raster processing with high compression

Tags: qgis, raster, model, compression

I am new to QGIS, please excuse my probably very easy question to which I couldnt find an easy solution:

I have many folders with each 9 raster files with different resolution (0.5 m - 2 m). In every of these folders I want every file on the same resolution (5 m) and the same layerextend to be merged in a second step and then retiled in a third step.

So far I do this manually 9 times with raster calculator in step 1, then manually merge these 9 files and then tile the resulting file. Is there anyway i can speed this up siginificantly (especially step one which is a lot of clicking) by using e.g. the graphic modeler?

**Update:** Ok, the "Model Designer" seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. For the raster calculator I can take one of the already processed files as template for the extend in Step 1. But I have a problem with the merging in step 2:
If I merge manually I use as "Additional creation options" -> "PROFILE->High Compression" from a drop-down menu. In the model designer there is no drop down menu and if I write "High Compression" into the field, he is giving me an error message while running. Does anyone know, what I have to write here to get the high compression while merging and retiling?

Comment: Inside the raster calculator I just define the layer extend and number of rows and columns to receive the 5 m resolution with the same reference for all 9 raster files.

Comment: I guess I have to add arguements from the profile in there, but in which format shall I do that? I cannot find anything about that. COMPRESS=DEFLATE doesn't work for example: "ERROR 4: COMPRESS=DEFLATE: No such file or directory"

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Does anyone has any clue clue on how to include compression while using the Model Designer? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same issue and found a solution to it. To include compression parameters in the graphical modeller, click on the show advanced parameters button in the translate tool - in Additional Creation Options enter the parameters in the following way "COMPRESS=DEFLATE|PREDICTOR=1|ZLEVEL=6" you can tweak the Predictor and Zlevel values as per your wish.